# SAS: How do I add a value with brackets and quotes in a data step?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide, datastep

I want to create a table using a data step in SAS that contains the display format codes for SSRS.

For example, I have some codes like this '#,0;(#,0)' but I am getting errors when I try to assign this value in a data step.  I also tried to put it in a macro first but it doesn't help.

Code:

```
%let fmt1 = %STR(#,0;(#,0)); *thousand-comma separator;

data FORMAT_XREF;   
    length METRIC_TYPE DSP_FORMAT $ 20;

    if  METRIC_TYPE = 'TOT_ACCT' then
            do;
                DSP_FORMAT = quote(&fmt1.);
            end;
run;
```

Error: 34         #,0;(#,0)
           _    _
           386  180
            _
            76
ERROR 386-185: Expecting an arithmetic expression.

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Comment: Arbitrarily adding macro to a program working or not is usually not a good idea.

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: @Airbum88 Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that you think the `quote` function does something different than it does.

The quote function adds double quote *characters* to something, not the quotations that will serve to delimit a character value.  It still takes a character value as input, which you're not providing it (a macro variable contains text, not character values, remember).

So you need:

```
%let fmt1 = %STR(#,0;(#,0)); *thousand-comma separator;

data FORMAT_XREF;   
    length METRIC_TYPE DSP_FORMAT $ 20;

    if  METRIC_TYPE = 'TOT_ACCT' then
            do;
                DSP_FORMAT = "&fmt1.";
            end;
run;
```

That should work fine for you.  If you actually need quotes in the value *also*, you can wrap the `quote` function around that (so `DSP_FORMAT = quote("&fmt1.");` will store `"#,0;(#,0)"` in the variable, including the `"` characters).

Comment: Thanks that works.  But if I try to add another line within the 'do' statement, like DSP_VALUE = 'Test'; I get an error but it doesn't have an error message.  I just see a red line and 49 in my Enterprise Guide.

Comment: `%let fmt1 = %STR(#,0;(#,0)); *thousand-comma separator;

data test;   
    length METRIC_TYPE DSP_FORMAT $ 20;

    if 1 then do;
                DSP_FORMAT = "&fmt1.";
                DSP_VALUE  = "something";
    end;
run;`  That works fine; you likely have something else wrong...